# on item click in array of string

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I made an android app in which the user click the favorite menu item button and the page name saves in the favorite.class activity. But when I click on any item in the favorite list it opens only one specific class and not others which I want. Here is my code please look at the code and tell me what should I do to make it first in `ListView` form and then to click the item which opens the correct activity from it.

`favorite.xml` layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="17dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/empty_textview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/no_bookmark"
        android:textSize="16sp" 
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bookmark_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:textSize="16sp" 
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
    <!-- ScrollView is needed when adding views, or only the last view will show up -->

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/bookmark_insert_point"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

`Favorite.Class` activity:

```
public class Favorite extends Activity {

    private TextView mEmptyText;
    private LinearLayout mBookmarkLayout;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.favorite);

        // this code is used for the action bar color change//
        ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
        bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#6B8E23")));
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true); 

        mEmptyText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.empty_textview);
        mBookmarkLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.bookmark_insert_point);

        getAllKeys();
    }
     private void getAllKeys()
    {
        SharedPreferences sp = this.getSharedPreferences("bookmarks", MODE_PRIVATE);
        Map<String,?> keys = sp.getAll();

        int count = 0;
        for(Map.Entry<String,?> entry : keys.entrySet())
        {
            String value = entry.getValue().toString();
            System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!value = "+value);
            String delimiter = ",";
            String[] values_array = value.split(delimiter);
            addBookmark(values_array);
            count++; //keep track of the number of bookmarks
        }

        //if there are no bookmarks, display a text view saying so.  Otherwise, make the text view go away
        if (count == 0)
        {
            mEmptyText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mEmptyText.setText(getString(R.string.no_bookmark));
        }
        else
            mEmptyText.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void addBookmark(final String[] values_array)
    {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = vi.inflate(R.layout.favorite, null);

        final TextView text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.bookmark_text);

        text.setText(values_array[1]);

        // insert into main view
        mBookmarkLayout.addView(v, 0, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!Just added a view");
        text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if(text.equals("Atherosclerosis"));
                Intent i=new Intent(Favorite.this,Atherosclerosis.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.favorite, menu);
      return true;
    }

}
```

and finally the activity from where user click for add to favorite:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Take appropriate action for each action item click


    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.id_search:
            Intent newActivity0 = new Intent(this,Search.class);     
            startActivity(newActivity0);
            return true;
        case R.id.id_favorit:
            SharedPreferences sp = this.getSharedPreferences("bookmarks", MODE_PRIVATE);
            Editor editor = sp.edit();
            editor.putString("atherosclerosis", "com.kmcpesh.shortreviewofcardiology.Favorite,Atherosclerosis");
            editor.commit();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Item Added to Favorite List!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well i guess what you have to do is setOnItemClickListener in everyone of the list items...
an example is

```
private void registerCallClickBack() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewClicked, int position,
                long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //String message = "You have chosen the " + id + "item";
            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent("package.Activity name");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

this will either display a toast message of every listview item clicked or start a new intent..

Comment: i havnt used listview for my favorite activity. i dont know how to save items in a listview. please see the second code Favorite.class